# What is the difference between smoothing and decomposition in time series?

Tags: r, time-series, smoothing

I am bit new to time series modelling, currently I am trying to understand some basics. What is the difference between smoothing and decomposition in time series. I have gone through many materials, I feel both are same. Please explain in simple way.

Answer (score 1):

To start with I will list 7 forecasting methods in time series.

1. Naive Approach
2. Simple Average
3. Moving Average
4. Simple Exponential Smoothing
5. Holt’s Linear Trend method
6. Holt-Winters Method
7. ARIMA

The first 4 methods try to make the rough edges of time series data smooth so as to correctly forecast the data.

[image: Image(s) to describe smoothing techniques in time series]

In the above image blue color shows the trend with true time series data while the red color shows the smoothed series.

The last 3 methods try to break down time series data into its various component such as `trend`, `season`, `cycle` and `residual` (remnant)

[image: Image(s) to describe decomposition in time series]

In the above image, I show what to expect in the decomposition of time series data

Answer (score 0):

It's different.
**Smoothing** like moving average outputs data smoothed.

**Decomposition** like seasonal decomposition outputs separating seasonality, trend, level, resid.